# Ignore a specifc value as a "No Data Value" in Spotfire

Tags: null, spotfire

I a have a data table where the data has been extracted from a larger model. In the ascii file, the "No Data Value" is set at -99999. I would like to bring this data into Spotfire, so is there a way I can get Spotfire to ignore this value (i.e., to consider it an empty value and not bring it in, or to not use it in a calculated column?)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when adding the data table, if you expand the Transformations panel on the Add Data Table dialog, you have the option to add a **Calculate and replace column** transformation. use an expression like

```
If([column] = -99999, null, [column])
```

just make sure that you select the correct column to replace at the top of the expression builder.